# Using LINQ to SQL with custom business model?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

When using LINQ to SQL am I forced to live with objects structured the same as the database? Or can I use a different modelling structure for my business models?

If it's possible, how can I make this change?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to pass around instances of linq-to-sql entity classes or exposing them publicly as they could be attached to the context. The general practice I believe is to create POCOs with same properties as the linq-to-sql entities and use something like AutoMapper to map back and forth b/w the two sets of entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own business model as DTO classes and copy the content to these DTO classes from your linq to sql objects. We used T3 templates (I don't remember where I got it...you can google it) to generate the DTOs to save the coding time and used [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) initially to convert from L2S objects to DTOs, however, we started getting AutoMapperException randomly with no clues. So, for all our new code, we have created helper class to do the conversion. The advantage of this approach is that, now your service can be consumed by even non .NET clients as DTOs are platform generic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, LINQ to SQL always works directly with the database. It is always a one to one mapping.

This is one of many reasons to use Entity Framework, which allows you to program against an entity model which will not necessarily map one to one to the database structure.